# Can't get a RightViewController to work with MEDynamicTransition

Tags: ecslidingviewcontroller

I'm trying to modify the TransitionFun example that comes with ECSlidingViewController to include a RightViewController.

I've basically added another ViewController, similar to the existing MenuViewController, that appears on a swipe to the left, (or from extra navigation item on Transition View Controller).

This works fine for the Default transitions but not for the others. Fold and Dynamic transitions jump and behave erratically, while the Zoom transition locks up the app!
(just to clarify - all the transitions initially work fine if I only use the existing left menu view - they only break after transitioning at least once to my new right view).

Has anyone managed to do anything similar? Maybe someone (Mike?) could update the demo to show how its done if possible?
Thanks